# Checking token for password reset in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, token

I have a database with one table called TOKENS.  It consists of:

e-mail, token, expired_date, password

How do I check to see if a value exists in a database column?  I need to check if the token exists.  I have tried querying the column "token" and then storing results in an array and checking if it exists in the array. Is this the best method?

Secondly, how can I query that token and check the corresponding expiry_date set? In Excel this would be like a VLOOKUP.  Basically I would query the token and return the expiry_date field of that token.

**More Info:**
I am creating a password reset script.  Right now the script checks if user exists in database, if so, generates a random token and expiry date and e-mails a reset link with the token appended to it in a query string.

When the user navigates to the reset.php page through their link, first I check if a password is set and if not show the password reset form (basically first visit will always show the form).

When a user clicks "reset" after entering their password, I need to check if the token is valid.

Comment: You're going to want to take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and then your query will look something like `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT token from TOKENS where email = $myEmail")`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I read over that page but couldn't find just a specific value.  Now I just need to check if a value exists in a column.

Comment: I hope you're following all of the usual guidelines regarding [application security in PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) because having a column called "password" is often a sign of using plain-text passwords.

Comment: @user2836489 Result will store the value.  You can do a `var_dump($result)` to see what it's pulling back and check it if it's empty/null.